# How can I get the value from html page which is assigned with inner function

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I want to get artist and the title of playing song on radio as a chrome extension. We can use this link as an example; http://www.radiogrenouille.com/

What I have done so far? I make a http request and get the html. And try to parse the song information.

popup.js

```
function httpGet(theUrl, callback)
{
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
  {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
        callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET", theUrl, true );
  xmlhttp.send();
}


window.onload = function() {
  httpGet("http://www.radiogrenouille.com/",function(result) {
    var el = document.createElement('html');
     el.innerHTML = result;
     console.log(el.querySelectorAll(".titreencours")[0].innerText);
  });
}
```

But `el.querySelectorAll(".titreencours")[0].innerText` returns empty string. What should I do? Is this because its value is set by `titresplayer` in the website? So how can I get the info?

manifest.json

```
{
  "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "description": "Add to playlist",
  "key": "MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtJPZPVU+/+uNH4xFmNWJuiGzSxWiiFnBcbqqdXaXaNegydbYC82Mio7967WfVSUFip1UWy2bJP1IVxPh9HK2CXH3W06RxvE99dafYPTGrB3ccb3KlFCdiwmNECxXAR9GY5hxyc5jsyeDWiJTDn+Fbs9XkLwndCsZx94/sInQvAjCv6FwtFj44S2t1+L7uTSSBzy1EagYkw4aocUOL+TJ4QNg2HG5iAHq/iezVrCPF81l+MQ4DaPAgSYb7gRLfS+CnKGBen9GeeoSL3AsjWJWbmGQuNOxUV+A0rduhWmaamTA6lGrxaqQE3ZMsEG83rQS866W/KJWbkrQLLg+D/022QIDAQAB",
   "manifest_version": 2,
   "name": "Add to playlist",
  "permissions": [ "https://*/*", "http://*/*", "tabs", "activeTab" ],
  "update_url": "https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
  "version": "1.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a **complete** [mcve] that *duplicates the problem*. Including a *manifest.json*, some of the background/content/popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: I edited the quesiton and add my manifest.json. I thought, I've explained the situation. I want to get the song title and artist but it returns empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing OK, your code logic is correct. BUT you should know that the page content is heavily Javascipt-generated.

What you got from your ajax request is just the server-rendered content.

If you press Ctrl+U to view source of the page, you will see the empty tag `<span class="titreencours"></span>`. That's why you got the empty string and not the title. The other tags are also empty.

```
            <div id="titreEnCours">
              <div class="contenutitreEnCours">
                <p><span class="titreencours"></span></p>
                <p><span class="artistetitreencours"><strong></strong> </span></p>
                <p class="albumencours"><span class="nom"></span> <span class="labelencours"></span></p>
                <p class="radioencours"></p>
              </div>
              <span></span>
            </div>
```

For your information, the page loads the playlist from 
http://www.radiogrenouille.com/wp-content/themes/radiogrenouille-new/cestpasse.php

Cheers.

Comment: exactly what happened is what you have said. how did you get this php link?

Comment: So. Just want to share one of my opinions on this (in case you still need to finish the job).  You can use content script that run on the web page. It will help you get the title, the artist name, or anything you want (if the page has async operation like ajax, you can do polling to workaround that). And, content script and popup script can talk to each other though background script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are attempting to do a cross-domain request, and the server you are connecting to does not allow it (`Access-Control-Allow-Origin` not set in response)...
A workaround can be to make the request from server-side code (like PHP `curl`) and make an ajax request to your server-side file (e.g. myAjax.php)

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked if you are getting the response page in 'result', As if you are trying from different origin then you might get 200 OK with empty response.

Comment: Answers should be used *only* to provide answers to the question. To request additional information from the OP, leave a comment on the Question. This is really a comment, not an answer. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](//stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).